# How to use custom HTML Helper methods in MVC web grid

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have to display images in web grid dynamically. I used custom HTML helpers to do that and it's working fine outside the web grid, but I don't know how to use it inside the grid. I use the script below:

```
public static class CustomHtmlHelpers
    {
      public static IHtmlString ViewDPByID(this HtmlHelper helper, string src, string alt, string cssclass)
            {
                TagBuilder tb = new TagBuilder("img");

                if (File.Exists("~/Assets/images/EmpDB/" + src + ".png"))
                    tb.Attributes.Add("src", VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Assets/images/EmpDB/" + src + ".png"));
                else
                    tb.Attributes.Add("src", VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Assets/images/angular.jpg"));

                tb.Attributes.Add("alt", alt);
                tb.Attributes.Add("class", cssclass);
                return new MvcHtmlString(tb.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
            }
}





 @webGrid.Table(
    htmlAttributes: new { @id = "WebGrid", @class = "table align-items-center table-flush table-hover table-sm" },
    headerStyle: "thead-light",
    columns: webGrid.Columns(
             //RowID
             webGrid.Column(header: "EmployeeID",
             format: @<span class="label">@Html.ViewDPByID(item.EmployeeID,"employee image", "avatar rounded-circle avatar-sm mr-3")</span>, style: "EmployeeID")),
                 footer: @<table class="footer">
            <tr>
            </tr>
        </table>)
```

I'm getting this error:
[[image]]

> 'HtmlHelper>' has no applicable method named 'ViewDPByID' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

Answer (score 0):

dynamic types in extension methods is not supported.
this should work

```cs
format: @<span class="label">@Html.ViewDPByID(((int)item.EmployeeID,"employee image", "avatar rounded-circle avatar-sm mr-3")</span>, style: "EmployeeID")),
```

Comment: still having this error [link](https://prnt.sc/pheq2w) @Paulo

Comment: Thanks man, its working fine. i user like this
 format: `@<span>@Html.ViewDPByID((string)Convert.ToString(item.EmployeeID), "Image placeholder", "avatar rounded-circle avatar-sm mr-3")</span>, style: "EmployeeID"),`